# Is there a way to execute this CURL request without printing the response?

Tags: php, curl

```
echo "<p style='display:none'>";
$url = 'https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/TRIGGER/with/key/MYKEY';
$ch = curl_init($url);
$xml = 'value1='.$_POST["name"].'&value2='.$_POST["overview"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$response = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
echo "</p>";
```

So this may stem from my lack of understanding on CURL, I haven't done much with it.
Is there a way to execute this request to IFTTT without the "You have successfully triggered..." showing up on my page? As you can see I have a sloppy fix that's working for now.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

From [the curl_setopt documentation](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt):

> **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**
>
> **TRUE** to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` instead of outputting it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true. From the Docs,

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```